Programmatically set model input (Signal) from parent and react to change in children
In my Angular 16 app, i have a parent component that pass myObj (a plain javascript object) to children component that is treated as a model<MyObj>
<!-- parent.component.html -->
  <app-children [myObjModel]="myObj"
                (myObjModelChange)="doSomething($event)">
  </app-children>

In my child component i handle myObj as a model input:
export class ChildrenComponent {
  myObjModel = model<MyObj>();

  onMyModelChange(event: MyObj) {
    this.myObjModel.set(event);
    doThings(event)
  }

  doThings(event: MyObj) {
    console.log("I changed value in: " + event);  
  }
}


It works fine as i modify the value in my children component, it trigger the doThings() function.
What if i want to react in children component if the value change programmatically from father component? (like i load a configuration in father and pass myObj to my children that should trigger a function)
If myObj in father component change, the doThings() function is not called and even if i subscribe to change of myObjModel (with .subscribe() API) it doesn't trigger.
I tried this in children component with no success:
  constructor() {
    this.myObjModel.subscribe((val) => {
      doThings(val);
    });
  }

I don't want to convert the model to input because i want to benefit from the two-way binding mechanism.

Using effect(()=> doThings(this. myObjModel())) does not resolve your problem?

@OscarLudick Not really. effect are supposed to be used for 'input' and not for 'model' API

@Pittogatto this is not true.

You can use the effect() function for model inputs. Accd. to the docs:

In other respects, you can use model inputs the same way you use
standard inputs. You can read the value by calling the signal
function, including in reactive contexts like computed and effect.

Try the following
child.component.ts
export class Child {
  public myObjModel = model<MyObj>();

  constructor() {
    effect(() => {
      const myObj = this.myObjModel();
      console.log('this.myObjModel change observed in effect()');
      if (myObj) {
        this.doThings(myObj);
      }
    });
  }

  onMyModelChange(event: MyObj) {
    this.myObjModel.set(event);
  }

  doThings(myObj: MyObj) {
    console.log('I changed value in: ', myObj);
  }
}

Working example: Stackblitz

Michael, if you want to use effect, inside you need "mentionate" myObjModel, e.g.effect(() => {this.doSomething(this.myObjModel());}) or effect(() => {if (this.myObjModel() || true)this.doSomething();})

@Eliseo: Would you be kind enough to provide doc links for "mentionate"? I couldn't find any through a rough skim search. So the this.myObjModel() need to be called inside the effect for it to be used?

sorry my english, I wnat to say that it's necessary appear in one way this.myObjectModel() inside the "effect function.", see e.g. this link. The author declare first the "signals that want to "observe":const myObject=this.myObject();...rest of code... Else don't execute. Take a look to this stackblitz and comment the line 35

@Eliseo: Many thanks for the links. And please don't bother, English isn't my first language as well :). You're right. My first answer worked as expected however, since the signal getter was called in the doThings() method. I've updated my answer so that it's triggered inside the effect.
